# How to set SerializedProperty.propertyType in a CustomPropertyDrawer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools, unity-editor

I am using these two libraries:

- Unity-SerializableDictionary:
  https://github.com/starikcetin/Unity-SerializableDictionary
- Unity Scene Reference:
  https://github.com/starikcetin/unity-scene-reference

Basically, the serializable dictionary looks at the propertyType to determine if the property can be expanded or not, with the following check:

```
static bool CanPropertyBeExpanded(SerializedProperty property)
{
    switch(property.propertyType)
    {
    case SerializedPropertyType.Generic:
    case SerializedPropertyType.Vector4:
    case SerializedPropertyType.Quaternion:
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, it appears that Scene Reference is registered as an expandable property even though it isn't. This is because -apparently- Unity registers it as of type `Generic`.

I can solve this simply by setting the `SerializedProperty.propertyType` to a more meaningful type, but it is read-only.

So, how can I set the `SerializedProperty.propertyType` of a custom property drawer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't documented but the type `Generic` is automatically assigned for any custom class (like e.g. `SceneReference`). You **can NOT** change the `propertyType` since it is **read-only** ... and you can't tell the compiler to handle your custom class as something else ...

Even **if** you could ... what would be a "more meaningful type"? The available types for [`SerializedPropertyType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedPropertyType.html) are limited and none of them is more meaningful for a custom class.

---

The main "issue" here is:

The `SerializableDictionary` drawer simply assumes that usually if you have a custom (`Generic`) class without a custom `PropertyDrawer` - so using the default drawer - it behaves exactly like the default drawer of `Quaternion` or `Vector4`:

[image]

- It has a label and foldout in the first line
- fields/content are/is drawn below and only if the property is folded out

Since the drawer for `SceneReference` doesn't implement this behavior it is drawn on top of the dictionary's key-field.

---

So as simplest fix of course you can simply remove the

```
case SerializedPropertyType.Generic:
```

so the `SceneAsset` (and **all other custom classes**) is treated like a normal unfolded field - a matter of taste

[image]

---

Alternatively what you could do about it is change the `PropertyDrawer` of `SceneReference` to reflect the behavior of e.g. `Quaternion`:

- Add an `EditorGUI.Foldout` with the label which changes the `property.isExpaned` value
- Move any content one line below (and optionally intended)
- Add one line to the property height and a condition for `if(!property.isExpanded)`

Might look e.g. like:

```
// Made these two const btw
private const float PAD_SIZE = 2f;
private const float FOOTER_HEIGHT = 10f;

public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
{
    // Move this up
    EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, GUIContent.none, property);
    {
        // Here we add the foldout using a single line height, the label and change
        // the value of property.isExpanded
        property.isExpanded = EditorGUI.Foldout(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, lineHeight), property.isExpanded, label);

        // Now you want to draw the content only if you unfold this property
        if (property.isExpanded)
        {
            // Optional: Indent the content
            //EditorGUI.indentLevel++;
            //{

            // reduce the height by one line and move the content one line below
            position.height -= lineHeight;
            position.y += lineHeight;

            var sceneAssetProperty = GetSceneAssetProperty(property);

            // Draw the Box Background
            position.height -= FOOTER_HEIGHT;
            GUI.Box(EditorGUI.IndentedRect(position), GUIContent.none, EditorStyles.helpBox);
            position = boxPadding.Remove(position);
            position.height = lineHeight;

            // Draw the main Object field
            label.tooltip = "The actual Scene Asset reference.\nOn serialize this is also stored as the asset's path.";


            var sceneControlID = GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive);
            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            {
                // removed the label here since we already have it in the foldout before
                sceneAssetProperty.objectReferenceValue = EditorGUI.ObjectField(position, sceneAssetProperty.objectReferenceValue, typeof(SceneAsset), false);
            }
            var buildScene = BuildUtils.GetBuildScene(sceneAssetProperty.objectReferenceValue);
            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
            {
                // If no valid scene asset was selected, reset the stored path accordingly
                if (buildScene.scene == null) GetScenePathProperty(property).stringValue = string.Empty;
            }

            position.y += paddedLine;

            if (!buildScene.assetGUID.Empty())
            {
                // Draw the Build Settings Info of the selected Scene
                DrawSceneInfoGUI(position, buildScene, sceneControlID + 1);
            }

            // Optional: If enabled before reset the indentlevel
            //}
            //EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
        }
    }
    EditorGUI.EndProperty();
}

public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
{
    var sceneAssetProperty = GetSceneAssetProperty(property);
    // Add an additional line and check if property.isExpanded
    var lines = property.isExpanded ? sceneAssetProperty.objectReferenceValue != null ? 3 : 2 : 1;
    // If this oneliner is confusing you - it does the same as
    //var line = 3; // Fully expanded and with info
    //if(sceneAssetProperty.objectReferenceValue == null) line = 2;
    //if(!property.isExpanded) line = 1;

    return boxPadding.vertical + lineHeight * lines + PAD_SIZE * (lines - 1) + FOOTER_HEIGHT;
}
```

---

Now it looks like e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class TestDict : SerializableDictionary<string, SceneReference> { }

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SceneReference NormalReference;

    public TestDict DictExample = new TestDict();
}
```

[image]

---

Comment: Hey, thanks for the effort. Would you like to send this as a PR on GitHub? I would love your name to be up there as a contributor.

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin You're welcome! Added it to git. I also had a Bug btw in the SerializedDictionary: When I had conflicting key names (due two both being empty strings) and hit `Reset` in the context menu I got a lot of exceptions and it was irrevertable (except by commenting out the broken dictionary and recompile)

Comment: Thanks for this!!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a class like this

```
public class Test
{
   public string stringProperty;
}
```

Now, trying to set propertyType is basically like trying to tell the compiler to change the property type on the class, which is not possible, cause its already wrote down as 'string'.

What you could do is

```
static bool CanPropertyBeExpanded(SerializedProperty property)
{
   float height = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(property);
   // Property expandable if its height is twice the single line height.
   return height >= EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 2;
}
```

Comment: Since this `SceneReference` property basically **has** two lines this won't change the behavior in the Inspector much.